# all images of past post messed up after changing theme

Tags: images, css

After I changed my wordpress theme, I realized that all past post are all messed up. I think is because the new theme is not interpreting "alignleft" the proper way. And I mean that because when I insert new images in new post, I have to change the "alignleft" to alignnone" so the images are display properly, and also the text. If I don't do that the images are one after the other, and the text is kind of hidden. Is there any script to set past images to display correctly. Here's a past post (bad formatting of post after theme change)
http://pctechtips.org/installing-windows-xp-ntbackup-on-vista/

here's a recent post using "alignnone" (display correctly)
http://pctechtips.org/installing-and-configuring-remote-access-in-windows-server-2012/

Answer (score 0):

Alignleft looks like it's behaving itself exactly as it should: aligning the image left and the text to the right of it. If you want your left aligned images to behave the same way as you 'align none' image, simply go to your style.css and remove 'float:left' from your .alignleft code:

```
.alignleft {
float: left;
margin:0 1em 1em 0;
}
```

You can also change the margins to suit.

Comment: Or if you're talking about a more elaborate fix, you could leave .alignleft as it is (floated left) for new posts/images, and make a separate stylesheet, eg. styleold.css that you only reference if posts are older than a specific date.